# Can anyone identify this mystery caterpillar?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this caterpillar in in El Cerrito, CA and was wondering what kind it is?

[image: mystery caterpillar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best assumption, [Gulf Fritillary Caterpillar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_fritillary) (*Agraulis vanillae*). I could be wrong though.

> The larva is a caterpillar which grows to approximately 4 cm (1.6 in) in length. It is bright orange in color and covered in rows of black spines. The spines are soft to the touch and do not sting, but the larva is poisonous if eaten. Source: Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks! The caterpillar looks like a close match and the adult butterflies do too!